# Нужна помощь с получением инвентаря в Steam

Tags: python, api, requests, steam

Мне нужно собрать все предметы в инвентаре стим профиля пользователя (CS:GO), использовал офф. апи, но оно не выдает кол-во предметов (если в инвентаре 10 одинаковых кейсов, выдаст только 1), соответственно обьективно расчитать цену инвентаря не выйдет. Могу использовать как куки файлы, так и стим айди профиля для анализа. Пишу на Python. Пробовал так же этот сервис "https://steam.tools/", но там как я понял даже для отправки запроса нужна капча, не работал с ней. Помогите пжлста

Comment: покажите вашу попытку использования офф. api. кому-то это может помочь в ответе на ваш вопрос

Comment: `def get_inventory(): # Проверяю инвентарь
    headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
    headers["Cookie"] = f"steamLoginSecure={Secure}; steamMachineAuth{ID}={SteamMachine}"
    inventory = requests.get(f"https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/{ID}/inventory/json/730/2/?l=english", cookies=headers).json()
    return inventory` Примерно такая функция получалась. Я не сохранил ту версию кода, но она была +- рабочая. Далее я отправлял запрос на апи другого сервиса для подсчета стоимости предметов и она выходила на 10$ меньше изза проблемы из вопроса

Comment: Надо было прямо в вопросе указать ваш код.

Comment: ой, вся табуляция слетела, простите

Comment: Поместите код в вопрос, выделите и поставьте ему свойство "код", тогда ничего не съедет

Comment: а как вы узнали, что стоимость инвентаря меньше ? Как вы получили эту ожидаемую стоимость ?

Answer (score 0):

Приведенный метод работ корректно.
Чтобы в этом убедиться можно сделать так:

```
steamID = '' # ваш steam id
gameID = '730' # 730 - CS:GO
inv = requests.get(f'http://steamcommunity.com/id/{steamID}/inventory/json/{gameID}/2?l=english').json()
print(len(inv['rgInventory']))
```

и вы увидете, что количество предметов равно тому, что отображается у вас в инвентаре.

**Объяснение**
Метод вовзращает словарь следующего образца:

```
{
    'success': <class 'bool'>
    'rgInventory': <class 'dict'>
    'rgCurrency': <class 'list'>
    'rgDescriptions': <class 'dict'>
    'more': <class 'bool'>
    'more_start': <class 'bool'>
}
```

Ключ `rgInventory` - словарь, отображающий инвентарь пользователя следующего вида:

```
{
    'itemID': {
        {
            'id': <class 'str'>
            'classid': <class 'str'>
            'instanceid': <class 'str'>
            'amount': <class 'str'>
            'hide_in_china': <class 'int'>
            'pos': <class 'int'>
        },
    'itemID': {
       ...
    },
    ...
    }
}
```

Из-за того, что ключами этого словаря являются `id` предметов, а не `id` их класса - количество предметов всегда = 1.

Comment: К сожалению, это не совсем то, что мне было нужно, у меня уже есть готовый код, который собирает инвентарь описанным тобой способом и через сторонний сервис собирает их стоимости, проблема в том, что офф. стим апи не дает узнать кол-во конкретного предмета

Comment: Я может быть некорректно описал суть вопроса.... Проблема в следующем: Допустим в инвентаре 10 предметов (все это например Кейс Расколотая сеть). Дело в том, что в результате запроса выше, ответ будет содержать в себе только ОДИН предмет и насколько я понял: невозможно указать реальное количество этих кейсов в инвентаре. Может быть я плохо проверил json, но как мне кажется проблема все таки в методе....

Comment: @FarshMak судя по тестам, `classid` как раз отображает название предмета. (но данных у меня довольно мало, попробуйте)